# FFmpeg writing to uncompressed numbered files

Tags: ffmpeg

I am having trouble writing uncompressed numbered files with FFmpeg using the `%04d` construct (for example).

This is fine with compressed formats such as JPEG and PNG, but for uncompressed high-quality formats such as yuv422p16le, if I don't use `-f image2`, FFmpeg tries to write to a single file.
For example, when I use `output.%04d.yuv`, I want the output to be `output.0000.yuv`, `output.0001.yuv` etc, but the actual output is a single file.

But when using `-f image2`, the output files are no longer uncompressed.
How can I get around this?

---

Here are some examples:

This command produces (unwantedly) compressed, numbered output files:
`ffmpeg -i input.mov -f image2 -pix_fmt yuv422p16le -pattern_type sequence output.%04d.yuv`

This command produces a single uncompressed output file called `output.%04d.yuv` (i.e. it does not expand the `%04d`):
`ffmpeg -i input.mov -pix_fmt yuv422p16le -pattern_type sequence output.%04d.yuv`

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the full commands you are using that are not working

Answer (score 0):

Select `rawvideo` video codec:

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -vcodec rawvideo -f image2 -pix_fmt yuv422p16le -pattern_type sequence output.%04d.yuv`

---

When video codec is unspecified, FFmpeg selects a default codec.
FFmpeg defines a default codec for each format (for each muxer).
The default codec for `image2` muxer is `mjpeg` (we can view the default codec using by executing: `ffmpeg -h muxer=image2`).
That is the reason why the output files are encoded in JPEG format when `-vcodec rawvideo` is unspecified.